# Making Payment via Paypal sends two confimation emails

Tags: paypal, order-email, magento2.2.3, transactional-mail

When I do payment using other payment methods its sending only one confirmation email one to user and one to admin , but when I use paypal as payment method it send two confirmation emails to admin and two to user ? Not sure whats happening here ?

```
UPDATE
```

I debugged more and found that I can make changes to `send()` method of `OrderSender` class , I tried changing it in core file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php` and it worked for me .

but I don't want to make changes to the core file so I created a custom plugin to achieve this

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="rahul_Sendorderplugin" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'rahul_Sendorderplugin',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="rahul\Sendorderplugin\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"></preference>
</config>
```

OrderSender.php

```
<?php

namespace rahul\Sendorderplugin\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{

    public function beforeSend(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        echo "hello";exit; // but its not working
    }
}
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help someone . I had fixed this issue by overriding the send() method as I mentioned in the question and checking if the email is already sent for the order or not . Below is the code snippet .

```
<?php
namespace rahul\Sendorderplugin\Model\Order\Email\Sender

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{

    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {

//$order->getEmailSent() will check if the email has been sent for order or not


            if ($this->checkAndSend($order) && !$order->getEmailSent()) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $order->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

This fixed the issue I was facing.